# Disadvantage of Using Linked Lists in Memory Management

Tags: algorithm, memory-management, bitmap, linked-list, operating-system

I'm kinda confused as to what the primary disadvantage of using a linked list would be in maintaining a list of free disk blocks. My professor said that using a bit map would help solve said problem. Why does using a bit map solve this problem?

To narrow down my questions:

1. What is the primary disadvantage of using a linked list in maintaining a list of free disk blocks?
2. Why does using a bit map solve this problem/disadvantage?

Comment: And **what is the original problem** in your case that linked lists or bit maps should solve? You mention "free disk blocks" but what about them? Allocation? Uniform disk block allocation frequency to minimize SSD drive or flash memory wear out? Without more focus on the problem there are no advantages/disadvantages other then linked lists are simple to implement, taught very early and every programmer can use them

Comment: @xmojmr It's just a sample exam question. This was all that was given.

Comment: In that case try to figure out by yourself (try to use it in simple (paper?) code modeling the disk manager) what are the differences when it comes to data structure access speed (read/write) and failure recovery. Your ability to think about it is one of the key things the exam is supposed to verify. Google query `file system allocation bitmap` points to many useful articles like [Wikipedia: Free space bitmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_space_bitmap) or [IJEAT: Allocation of Free Disk Blocks in UNIX using Bitmaps](http://www.ijeat.org/attachments/File/v3i1/F2120082613.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

Hi,

**What is the primary disadvantage of using a linked list in maintaining a list of free disk blocks?**

- This scheme is not very efficient since to traverse the list, we must read each block requiring substantial time.
- The second disadvantage is additional memory requirement for maintaining linked list of all free disk blocks.

**Why does using a bit map solve this problem/disadvantage?**

- Most often the list of free disk spaces is implemented as a bit map or bit vector. Each block is represented by a single bit. 0(zero) is marked as a free block whereas 1 is for allocated block. So, no need of extra extra memory to store free disk space.
- Fast random access allocation check: Checking if a sector is free is as simple as checking the corresponding bit. so traversal is faster than LinkedList.

Other Advantage of using Bit Map:

- Fast deletion: Data need not be overwritten on delete, flipping the corresponding bit is sufficient

May this helps you. Fill free for further clarification.

Regards,

Bhavik

Comment: A linked list of free blocks doesn't require any memory, assuming the minimum size block is big enough.

Comment: ya you can say that, but comparing to bitmap it is using less memory.

Comment: Also, bit map is easier to find contiguous blocks

Comment: Traversal of a free-block list is unnecessary.  When you need a block, take the first one in the list.  When you free a block, add it to the beginning of the list.  Random access is not required for these tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution was given by @FullDecent in the comments to the other answer (he deserves your bounty).  To elaborate:

Assuming that the disk drive in question is of the older, conventional type, with a spinning storage surface and a read/write head that physically moves radially across the surface...

In general it is good for files to be stored as contiguously on disk as possible, so that multiple blocks can be read sequentially.  If a file is "fragmented" (its blocks are scattered in different places on the disk), the drive head will need to be repositioned several times to read the entire file.  Repositioning of the head is one of the most time-consuming operation involved in a disk read (second only to starting the disk spinning after it has been stopped).  Hence the procedure known as "defragmentation" or "defragging", which rearranges the used blocks on a disk to make all files contiguous.

With a linked list of free blocks, allocation involves taking blocks from the front of the list, and deallocation involves adding freed blocks to the front of the list.  Hence the list can get messy, with blocks that are not adjacent on the disk frequently being adjacent in the list.  To find a contiguous stretch of free blocks large enough for a large file, it may be necessary to scan a significant fraction of the list.

With a bitmap, it will still be necessary to scan for a large contiguous free block section, but this is easier since 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits (depending on the hardware's word size) can be checked in a single operation.